# How to fix ownerState.color typescript error in MUI V5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image: How can I fix this typescript error from MUI V5?]

I need to override the hover colors of buttons to light instead of dark, for all the buttons, I tried to do it with ownerState of buttons, but I have issue with the type of ownerState

Answer (score 0):

This is because the type of `color` in `ownerState` is not defined by default. So, you can create your own custom `ownerState` type with the `color` property.

```
interface YourCustomButton {
 ownerState: {
 hoverColor?: string;
 color?: string;
 };
}

const CustomButton = styled(Button)<YourCustomButton>(({ theme, ownerState }) => ({
  backgroundColor: ownerState.hoverColor || 'your_color',
  color: ownerState.color || 'your_color',
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: ownerState.hoverColor || 'your_color',
    color: ownerState.color || 'your_color',
  },
}));
```

Now, you can use the custom button to pass the hover color.

```
<CustomButton ownerState={{ hoverColor: 'your_color', color: 'your_color' }}>
  Click my body -;
</CustomButton>
```

Comment: But im trying to do it on the Theme himself, not on custom buttons, so how i declare the ownerState of regular buttons (like success,info etc...)

Comment: Okay, that means you have to customize them's component object.  This will help you: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/